# Python imaplib display certificate key

Tags: python, security, ssl, certificate, imaplib

I want imaplib to display the md5 (or SHA) key of an IMAP Server Certificate to make sure, that there's no MITM (I don't trust the CA, so verifying the chain isn't enough in this case).

Displaying the whole certificate would also be okay.

I'd appreciate any help!!

- Chris

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [M2Crypto package](http://wiki.python.org/moin/M2Crypto) to parse the full SSL certificate from the IMAP connection's SSL socket.  Here is an example:

```
import imaplib
from M2Crypto import X509

cn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
sock = cn.ssl()
data = sock.getpeercert(1)
cert = X509.load_cert_string(data, X509.FORMAT_DER)
print cert.get_fingerprint()
```

Prints:

```
2029AF27C0A55390D670C0BD7AB9747
```

Use the other attributes on `cert` to get further information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it from imaplib, but you can connect to a secure IMAP server and display the certificate using [M2Crypto](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/):

```
from M2Crypto import SSL                                                                            
ctx = SSL.Context('sslv3')                                                                          
c = SSL.Connection(ctx)                                                                             
c.connect(('localhost', 993)) # automatically checks cert matches host                              
cert = c.get_peer_cert()                                                                            

print cert.as_pem()                                                                                 
print cert.as_text()
```

Note that `cert` is an [X509 object](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.X509.X509-class.html).

Comment: Thank you. I'll use samplebias solution, because he takes the cert directly from the same connection. nevertheless thanks again.